# add a point on mouse click event on highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a requirement on highcharts that when I click on the chart it should draw a point.Currently I'm drawing lines between the clicked points.But I want also point marker where it is clicked.
Here is my code to add custom lines on highcharts-

```
var all_points= []; 
var all_str="";

chart: {
    events: {
        click: function(event) {
var x1=event.xAxis[0].value;

var y1=event.yAxis[0].value;                                

selected_point='['+x1+','+y1+']';

all_points.push(selected_point);
all_str=all_points.toString();


if(all_points.length>1)
{

this.addSeries({                            
type : 'line',
name : 'Trendline'+(j++),
id: 'trend',    
data: JSON.parse("[" + all_str + "]"),                                                                  

color:'#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16), 
});
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle for the same and share with us.

Comment: Take look at the chart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-click-to-add

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the below. Though I am not sure what chart you are using.

```
click: function(e) {
    var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
    y = e.yAxis[0].value,
    series = this.series[0];
    series.addPoint([x, y]);
 }
```